# Menu bar app for plain text/markdown notes?

Tags: menu-bar, dropbox, markdown

I'm converting from Evernote to Dropbox/Markdown for my notes. And I really love the quick note capture menu bar applet for Evernote (image below).

[image]

Anyone know of something similar for plain text notes? Ideally it quickly stores the note as a `.md` file in `~/Dropbox/Notes`. But .txt files can also work. This is on macOS Sierra.

Comment: Can you please provide details of the device and version of OS you're using?

Comment: See [this post](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/2181/88313) for important guidelines that should be followed when asking for a software recommendation. It will help everyone by preventing unnecessary answers for items that don't fit your request.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend NValt, a fork of Notational Velocity:

http://brettterpstra.com/projects/nvalt/

It doesn't work in the menubar, but you can configure a shortcut to show/hide the NV window if you want. It's also got a built in search, kind of like spotlight, which you can use to open notes quickly. 
Here's a screenshot:

[image: NValt screenshot]

By default it saves the files in a database, but you can also save the notes in a specified directory as plaintext, RTF or HTML files. Or you can synchronize it with [Simplenote](https://simplenote.com/) (but Dropbox will work just as well if you use files/db). Markdown support is not first class, but it works when you save as RTF or HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I am searching for something like that too. I tried Curiota but missed the ability to take quick screenshots and audio notes from the Evernote Helper.

So my current solution is about just using the Evernote Helper (without Evernote running) to jot down text, images or taking screenshots/audio notes and then selecting the contents using [command ⌘] A and sending it the app of choice (granted it has a Services menu item). I don't need to have Evernote running to use the menu bar item so it is ok for me.

I never actually save to Evernote. When I have some time I will write an importer to do the importing for me. The beautiful thing is that if you write in markdown and send it to a Markdown app the formatting will be clean!

[image: Evernote Helper Settings]

But searching for a better solution better as well.